# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php

Trying to get this code to work, but I keep running into errors.  I am fairly new to PHP and doing a project for personal learning.  Thank you in advance for any help!

If I cut the following code out it will run fine.  The code with the ** is the code that is throwing the error.

[15-Jul-2012 03:10:01 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in x.php on line 22

```
var $salt = 'fortesting';
var $userpw = 'testing';
**var $saltpw = $salt . $userpw;**
var $tpw = hash('sha512', $saltpw, false);
```

Comment: Please , don't make stuff up. Get a beginner's book about PHP and read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is a part of properties class' declaration.

Well, you can only specify constant value for properties. So you cannot concatenate strings there.

The possible solution would be to initialize the `saltpw` property in runtinme in class' constuctor, like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->saltpw = $this->salt . $this->userpw;
}
```

PS: `var` is obsolete, you should use `private`, `protected` or `public` instead

Comment: Appreciate the information very much from the responses.  Learned I cannot use concatenation in the declaration area for classes!  Creation of a constructor fixed it, thanks again!